# Storing a very large string in a mips .asciiz

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, mars-simulator

I want to store a string like this in the .data section in this type of of format:

```
  str: .asciiz
  "*************************************/n
   *                                   */n
   *                                   */n
   *                                   */n
   *                                   */n
   *                                   */n
   ************************************* "
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to store it in a single line like:

```
  str: .asciiz "*************************************/n*                                   */n*                                   */n.....etc
```

Comment: You want `\n` for newline not `/n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want the second method. Different simulators may not have support for multi-line strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can store each section of the string as a .ascii except the last one, which you can store as a .asciiz. When you print out using the "str" address, it should keep printing until it hits a null, which would be at the end of the last line. Ex:

```
str:
    .ascii  "This is a really long "
    .ascii  "sentence that I might want "
    .ascii  "to split up into "
    .asciiz "multiple lines."
```

Printing this with just one syscall (of course with the address of str in $a0) gives you "This is a really long sentence that I might want to split up into multiple lines"